# Typescript call Object method from variable

Tags: typescript

I have a node buffer

```
const meter = {
   readFunction: 'readUIntLE',
}
const buf = Buffer.from('01590D000022B65160010044BC1F000003036801', 'hex')
const method = meter.readFunction
```

I want to execute `buf[method](0,1)` but **typescript** warns me with an error

**Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'**

**Eval** doesn't look good to execute, but I am not too sure how to get rid or an error by other means

Comment: sorry revised code

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your object is typed as

```
readFunction: string
```

and not

```
readFunction: 'readUIntLE'
```

so TS doesn't see that the `buf[method]` refers to the method you want - it just sees an arbitrary string, which could be anything.

Declare the object `as const` to avoid the problematic widening.

```
const meter = {
    readFunction: 'readUIntLE' as const,
}
```

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you can consider marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)